# curl in bash error "Your browser does not support scripts or has been configured not to allow scripts."

Tags: bash, curl, scripting

I am new to curl.
I have created a bash script with curl to download a report from a website.
I am able to authenticate and set cookies and access the report page.
However the report is run in Iframe.
I am stuck at two places.

1. I am getting an error while I invoke the post method to run the report.
2. How to click on the iframe option to download the report after it is run (options such as save in pdf/excel/other are provided in the report widget) .

```
Here is the error message:

================================================================================================== 

 Your browser does not support scripts or has been configured not to allow scripts.

                                                                                                                                                    Your browser does not support scripts or has been configured not to allow scripts.

Report Viewer Configuration Error

   The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application's web.config file. Add  to the system.web/httpHandlers section of the web.config file, or
   add  to the system.webServer/handlers section for Internet Information Services 7 or later.
   [Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=10.0.40219.329&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.SpinningWhee
   l.gif] Loading...
   Cancel
   Show / Hide Parameters
   Show / Hide Document Map                                    
==================================================================================================
```

Comment: The web site uses JavaScript to generate its data dynamically. `curl` doesn't run JavaScript. You'll need to use something like Selenium WebDriver.

Comment: I would be surprised if that's possible. As far as I know curl is only for single requests but not to click around on a website. In any case it would be helpful to see the current code.

Comment: I have switched to selenium and job is done. Thank you @@Barmar for your suggestion. 

Now I need help to close this question.